# loop unrolling effect on dl1 cache miss

Tags: caching, compiler-optimization

I know that loop unrolling can sometimes increase the Instruction level cache miss, but i have noticed (in simple scalar sim-cache), that loop unrolling is decreasing dl1 cache miss( i am using other cache as none , so no other cache exists) , but i did not get the logic behind this, how come loop unrolling can reduce data level cache miss ?

Loop unrolling will cause the same number of load words as in without unroll case right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some situation , like access is restricted in form of column major( we can not do that in row major), and have large column size, so one each miss, one cache line is brought into the cache but only one element is used, So if we can use another element of that cache line by unrolling it ( matrix transpose ), will reduce miss rate.